# Получить строку из текста

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой текст
[

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html lang='en' style='padding-top:0px;' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<link href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/stylesheets/mpro_lite.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/stylesheets/yandex-search-lite.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<title>Зона бесплатного интернета</title>
 
</head>
<body style='background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 240px; max-width: 500px; text-align:left; background:none;'>
<div id='proxy_container'>
<div id='user_bar'>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='authorization'>
<tr>
<td align='left' style="background:url('http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/bg_authorization.jpg') bottom repeat-x #CECED1"><a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/ml/?owner_id=7344825&amp;c=account&amp;m=view" class="font_95">madzal123</a></td>
<td align='right' style="background:url('http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/bg_authorization.jpg') bottom repeat-x #CECED1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class='t-logo-date' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td align='left' style='background-color:#FFF; background:none;'>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/home"><img alt="Logo_mf" height="22" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/logo_mf.png?1458293357" width="100" /></a>
</td>
<td align='right' style='background-color:#FFF; background:none;'>
<img align='right' src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/18+/18plus-gr.png' />
<div style='float: right;margin-top: 4px;margin-right: 7px;'>
19
марта
2016
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 
<div class='tmenu'>
<table style='border:0; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;'>
<tr>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/home"><img alt="Btn_home_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_home_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/vpnew"><img alt="Btn_vpnew_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_vpnew_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/mfiles"><img alt="Btn_mfiles_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_mfiles_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=1399&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.megafonpro.ru%2Fvideo"><img alt="Btn_video_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_video_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=2265&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmuz.megafonpro.ru%2F"><img alt="Btn_music_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_music_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/chat"><img alt="Btn_chat_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_chat_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
<td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
<a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=22&amp;template=sub_WAP1cl&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwap.megafonpro.ru%2Fis3nwp%2Fproxy%2Fwap%2Fmp%2Fmain.mul.jsp&amp;nick=madzal123&amp;user_id=7344825"><img alt="Btn_rss_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_rss_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 
<div class='banner'>
<a href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/1/go?uid=2b0e2cd1427f3766e89587c95eeb9bd5'>
<image src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/1/image?size=480x80&amp;region=&amp;uid=2b0e2cd1427f3766e89587c95eeb9bd5'></image>
</a>
</div>
 
 
<p>
ВНИМАНИЕ! Переходя по ссылке вы покидаете бесплатный портал МегаФон.
Трафик будет тарифицировать согласно вашему тарифному плану.
</p>
<p>
Перейти по ссылке?
</p>
<p>
<a href="http://www.google.ru/">ДА</a>
<a href="javascript:history.back()">НЕТ</a>
</p>
 
<div class='banner'>
<a href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/2/go?uid=98475ec353a80d64525206bc1cc13733'>
<image src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/2/image?size=480x80&amp;region=&amp;uid=98475ec353a80d64525206bc1cc13733'></image>
</a>
</div>
 
<div class='yandex-search'>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://m.megafonpro.ru/poisk" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
<fieldset class='search-field'>
<table>
<td class='yandex-logo'>
<div>
<input id="ie" name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8" />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
</td>
<td class='search-button'>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Найти" />
</td>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
 
</div>
 
<div class='contentWidgets'>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='newsToday' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/rules">Правила</a>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/help">Помощь</a>
<a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/ml/?c=account&amp;m=my_main">Мой профиль</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

нужно получить только http://www.google.ru/ из текста,вот он в этом участке кода

```html
<a href="http://www.google.ru/">ДА</a>
```

Как быть ?
Можно было бы просто

```js
mystring.match(/<a href="\D{21}"/)
```

Но в href может быть любая ссылка

Comment: Для начала словами сформулируйте как отличить "правильную" ссылку, от "неправильной". И если вы в JS, зачем же html парсить регулярными выражениями, если есть функции работы с DOM. типа `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href`

Comment: @Mike представляете, частенько бывает так, что JS есть, HTML есть, парсить надо, а вот DOM то и нету. Есть конечно штуки вроде [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Answer (score 1):

C использованием jquery можно так.

```js
var linksArray = [];
$(function() {
  var googleLinks = $('a[href*=google]');
  googleLinks.each(function(i, el) {
    linksArray.push($(el).attr('href'));
  });
  console.log(linksArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html lang='en' style='padding-top:0px;' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>

<head>
  <link href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/stylesheets/mpro_lite.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/stylesheets/yandex-search-lite.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <title>Зона бесплатного интернета</title>

</head>

<body style='background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 240px; max-width: 500px; text-align:left; background:none;'>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">test google link</a>
  </div>
  <div id='proxy_container'>
    <div id='user_bar'>
      <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='authorization'>
        <tr>
          <td align='left' style="background:url('http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/bg_authorization.jpg') bottom repeat-x #CECED1"><a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/ml/?owner_id=7344825&amp;c=account&amp;m=view" class="font_95">madzal123</a>
          </td>
          <td align='right' style="background:url('http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/bg_authorization.jpg') bottom repeat-x #CECED1"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class='t-logo-date' width='100%'>
        <tr>
          <td align='left' style='background-color:#FFF; background:none;'>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/home">
              <img alt="Logo_mf" height="22" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/logo_mf.png?1458293357" width="100" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td align='right' style='background-color:#FFF; background:none;'>
            <img align='right' src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/18+/18plus-gr.png' />
            <div style='float: right;margin-top: 4px;margin-right: 7px;'>
              19 марта 2016
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class='tmenu'>
      <table style='border:0; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;'>
        <tr>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/home">
              <img alt="Btn_home_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_home_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/vpnew">
              <img alt="Btn_vpnew_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_vpnew_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/mfiles">
              <img alt="Btn_mfiles_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_mfiles_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=1399&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.megafonpro.ru%2Fvideo">
              <img alt="Btn_video_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_video_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=2265&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmuz.megafonpro.ru%2F">
              <img alt="Btn_music_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_music_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/chat">
              <img alt="Btn_chat_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_chat_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td height='35' style='text-align:center; padding:0; background:url(http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/tmenu-bg-sep.png) right no-repeat'>
            <a href="http://wap.megafonpro.ru/is3nwp/psmf/generate?service_id=22&amp;template=sub_WAP1cl&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwap.megafonpro.ru%2Fis3nwp%2Fproxy%2Fwap%2Fmp%2Fmain.mul.jsp&amp;nick=madzal123&amp;user_id=7344825">
              <img alt="Btn_rss_off" src="http://m.megafonpro.ru/images/btn_rss_off.gif?1458293357" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; border:none" />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class='banner'>
      <a href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/1/go?uid=2b0e2cd1427f3766e89587c95eeb9bd5'>
        <image src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/1/image?size=480x80&amp;region=&amp;uid=2b0e2cd1427f3766e89587c95eeb9bd5'></image>
      </a>
    </div>


    <p>
      ВНИМАНИЕ! Переходя по ссылке вы покидаете бесплатный портал МегаФон. Трафик будет тарифицировать согласно вашему тарифному плану.
    </p>
    <p>
      Перейти по ссылке?
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.google.ru/">ДА</a>
      <a href="javascript:history.back()">НЕТ</a>
    </p>

    <div class='banner'>
      <a href='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/2/go?uid=98475ec353a80d64525206bc1cc13733'>
        <image src='http://m.megafonpro.ru/bps/2/image?size=480x80&amp;region=&amp;uid=98475ec353a80d64525206bc1cc13733'></image>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class='yandex-search'>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://m.megafonpro.ru/poisk" method="get">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        </div>
        <fieldset class='search-field'>
          <table>
            <td class='yandex-logo'>
              <div>
                <input id="ie" name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class='search-button'>
              <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Найти" />
            </td>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div class='contentWidgets'>
      <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='newsToday' width='100%'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/rules">Правила</a>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/help">Помощь</a>
            <a href="http://m.megafonpro.ru/ml/?c=account&amp;m=my_main">Мой профиль</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```